# "Unable to connect to X server" after TTY login

Tags: ubuntu, x11

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10. Whenever I login on the command line (tty1-tty6) I get the following output:

```
Last login: ...
Welcome to Ubuntu 13.10 ...

Unable to connect to X server
Unable to connect to X server
```

And then the regular prompt.  I'm wondering if there is a way to track down what is causing the "Unable to connect to X server" message.  What processes/files run when I login this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore those messages if you like. They're attempts by your shell to establish connections to your X (Unity) desktop.

#### Debugging

If you're really driven to debug these you can try enabling debug messages in your login configuration files. Try adding `set +x` to your `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` files, or which ever configuration files your environment is using. You can disable it like this, `set -x`.

I'll often wrap these around blocks of commands that I want to see more verbose output from.

#### Example

In my `.bashrc` file.

```
...
set +x
# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi
set -x
...
```

Now when I log into the system.

```
...
New release '13.04' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

You have mail.
Last login: Tue Jan 21 19:15:05 2014 from greeneggs.bubba.net
++ alias 'll=ls -alF'
++ alias 'la=ls -A'
++ alias 'l=ls -CF'
++ alias 'alert=notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'
++ '[' -f /home/manny/.bash_aliases ']'
++ shopt -oq posix
++ '[' -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ']'
++ . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
+++ [[ himxBH == *v* ]]
+++ BASH_COMPLETION_ORIGINAL_V_VALUE=+v
+++ [[ -n '' ]]
+++ set +v
...
```

Comment: This worked, but I eventually just used some echo statements to track down a call I was making to `xinput` in my `.zshrc` file. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There definitely are ways to track this down.  First off, you could use strace on an "su -" command; that might do the trick.  Or, perhaps an strace of a simple "bash -il" might work.

```
strace -f -o su.trace su - $(whoami)
strace -f -o bash.trace bash -il
```

Try one (I recommend the bash one first) and see if it reproduces the output.  Note the "-o" option redirects the traced output to a file.  If you're not familiar with strace, the output can be a bit much to filter through.

Secondly, placing debug statements in RC scripts (like .bashrc) could be used to track them down.

Comment: This worked, but it was definitely harder to track down the statement using `strace`. Thanks for the reply!